# MongoDB Collections format

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I need to store restaurants with their corresponding menu items, so i did something like this

```
{ name: 'Foo',
  menu: 
 [ { item: 'foo',
   description: '...',
   price: 20 },
 { item: 'bar',
   description: '...',
   price: 30 } ]
}
```

The problem is i sometimes need to access this items, but it's not easy doing this, should i instead use something like this?

```
{ name: 'Foo',
menu: 
{ "0": { item: 'foo',
   description: '...',
   price: 20 },
 "1": { item: 'bar',
   description: '...',
   price: 30 } }
}
```

I think it's cheaper to find an specific item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using embedded objects accessible via numbered keys is rarely the right approach.  MongoDB has operators to facilitate accessing items within arrays that provide much better flexibility.

See the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) and [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/) projection operators for ways to pull out just the array element you need.

For instance, to get the `'foo'` menu item from your first example doc:

```
db.restaurants.findOne({name: 'Foo'}, {menu: {$elemMatch: {item: 'foo'}}});
```

Comment: dunno why im getting "uncaught exception: error { "$err" : "Unsupported projection option: $elemMatch", "code" : 13097 }"

Comment: @jtomasrl What version of MongoDB are you running?  `$elemMatch` was added in 2.2.